# Get question with newest answer SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a model like:

Question
     - Id
     - CreatedOn

Answer
     - Id
     - CreatedOn
     - QuestionID

No I want to get the first question with the newest answer.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: In one row? eg Oldest question with latest answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select top 1 *
from questions, answers
where question.id = answers.questionid
order by answers.createdon desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

SELECT TOP 1 Question FROM Questions JOIN Answers ON Questions.Id=Answers.QuestionID ORDER BY Answers.CreatedOn DESC;

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 Question from questions
  inner join answers on questions.Id = answers.QuestionId
order by answers.CreatedOn desc
```

Sorry for the delay in replying to the comment, I didn't have time earlier to test it out:

This gets more complicated, but something like this should work:

```
select top 5 Question from questions
  inner join answers on questions.Id = answers.QuestionId
GROUP BY Question
ORDER BY max(answers.CreatedOn) desc
```

This seems to be the [standard pattern](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx) to effectively get a distinct set of data from a table without including the order by column in the record set.

Be aware that the number of elements you want to select (in this case 5) has to be a constant in SQL. If you have the advantage of using something like LINQ to SQL, you could write this in LINQ and have the take amount as a variable.

So, in response to the latest comment, you'd just add max(answers.CreatedOn) to the select statement:

```
select top 5 Question, max(answers.CreatedOn)
from questions
  inner join answers on questions.Id = answers.QuestionId
GROUP BY Question
ORDER BY max(answers.CreatedOn) desc
```

Comment: Hi, If I want to get the Top 5 I have duplicates. Could you tell me how to create the query for distinct top 5 questions?

Comment: Sounds good. Just one last question. I want to get the date of lates answer from the answers table in the query, too. So QuestionId and its related alias "LastAnswerDate" in one query.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
SELECT Id, CreatedOn    
FROM Question Q    
WHERE Q.id IN    
(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 A.QuestionID FROM Answer A ORDER BY A.CreatedOn)
```

Comment: I have a problem: A.CreatedOn is not accepted because it is not in the select part of the subquery, any tip?

Comment: What if you try this?

SELECT DISTINCT Id, CreatedOn    
FROM Question AS Q
WHERE Q.id IN
(SELECT TOP 5 A.QuestionID 
FROM Answer A 
WHERE A.QuestionId = Q.id ORDER BY A.CreatedOn)


The SQL does not permit to make distinct query among with order by